# How to handle select-or-insert operation with jdbcTemplate in shared DB

Tags: sql, spring, transactions, locking

I've got some basic case and I'd appreciate some suggestions how to deal with that...

There is `some_table` in existing DB with two columns:

- auto-incremented key
- and a `name` describing the entry

I've got application using Spring 4 and `jdbcTemplate` to handle DB operations.

1. Application instance A:

   - searches for entry with given name `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name='name1'`

     - if it finds one it gets its key
     - if not, it creates new entry `INSERT INTO some_table (name) VALUES ('name1')`

       - and then it gets its key
   - use retrieved key for further processing...
2. Instance B may do the same at the same time.

So it may happen that both applications do `SELECT` at the same time for the same name that doesn't exist at the moment and then these both will `INSERT` new entries with same names and different keys.

How to synchronize them - what is the best practice here? Can application somehow lock `some_table` until it creates new entry or decide that it is not necessary and then release the lock? Is it possible to do this using Spring `jdbcTemplate`? How?

It seems like some basic case for me for which probably there are some patterns and I'd not want to reinvent the wheel... Any hints?

Or maybe the whole idea of using one DB instance directly by 2 application is a total design flaw?

Comment: okay, if you could share your code, it would be helpful. Did you try with `synchronized`  blocks? If not, can you add this to your methods firing sql queries to database?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html might give you some overview on `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: Please have in mind that this question is not about synchronizing blocks of code / operations in one application. There are 2 application instances using single DB instance - synchronization would have to take place on DB/SQL level. I could introduce another application that would be an interface/proxy to DB (it would synchronize requests), but maybe there is another/easier way...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The code that inserts the data needs to be prepared to handle a unique key violation. Other then that I see nothing wrong with that  approach

Answer (score 0):

INSERT IF NOT EXIST done with mutex table seems to do the trick in this case (found [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/25/insert-if-not-exists-queries-in-mysql/)):

```
INSERT INTO some_table(name) SELECT (?) FROM mutex LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table ON some_table.name = ? WHERE mutex.i = 1 AND some_table.name is null
```

Where `mutex` is created as follows:

```
create table mutex(
    i int not null primary key
);
insert into mutex(i) values (0), (1);
```

Each application can now execute:

- INSERT IF NOT EXIST whit name = 'name1'
- SELECT where name = 'name1', get its key and use it for further processing...

And only one of them will create new entry, so no duplicates should arise.

Now I need some solution for the case where name should be generated as an unique identifier, so the same key retrieved should not be used by 2 application instances...